# Swift iOS app storing more Documents & Data than expected

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am storing images in my app (~100 KB each) from the web. However when I store ~70 images, there is over 100 MB saved in the documents & data. Has anyone encountered this problem before? I am using these lines to save images:

```
let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
pngImageData!.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

Let me know if you need anymore info. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not think about the memory size of each image as it was originally. Think about its _pixel_ size. What are the pixel sizes of these images? Multiply that out by the byte size of a pixel and think about that.

Comment: Thanks Matt! That makes more sense now. I'm saving 960x960 sized photos. Is there any way I can store it as its original memory size?

Comment: Sure, don't take their `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. Just save the data you got "from the web" straight to disk.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try it out right now :)